# Renaming a list of 'Filename' inside a folder, with Prefix+'(existing)Filename' . For every file. using command promt/batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename

For example : Suppose we have 4 files inside a folder,

```
1656088200108CONTPE_CONR.txt
1656174600239CONTPE_NTSL.txt
1656261000254CONTPE_PMLL.txt
1656174600114CONTPE_CONR.txt
```

I wanted to add 'CONTPE_' in the beginning of every file.
Then i want to replace the filename as :

```
CONTPE_1656088200108CONTPE_CONR.txt
CONTPE_1656174600239CONTPE_NTSL.txt
CONTPE_1656261000254CONTPE_PMLL.txt
CONTPE_1656174600114CONTPE_CONR.txt
```

But there are incremental files in the folder. So destination code shouldn't be static/pre-defined.

I tried to do various code like:

1. `ren *CONTPE*.* CONTPE_*`
2. `ren *CONTPE*.* CONTPE_????*.*`

All the above methods, replaces the first characters in filename with `CONTPE`, thus outputs are like `CONTPE_000254CONTPE_PMLL.txt`, which is basically trimming the actual filename however I wanted as `CONTPE_1656261000254CONTPE_PMLL.txt`.

Screenshot will describe the problem.

[image: Secrrenshot]

Comment: My first instinct is just WHY? I could understand this ```1656261000254CONTPE_PMLL.txt``` to this ```CONTPE_1656261000254_PMLL.txt```, but not ```CONTPE_1656261000254CONTPE_PMLL.txt```.

Comment: CONTPE_1656261000254CONTPE_PMLL.txt, this is the standard readable format which has to be put under the server folder. So the application could read those files starting with 'CONTPE_' . 
The CONTPE_1656261000254_PMLL.txt in this, text you are extracting 'CONTPE' from middle of the filename, which is not recommended. As the file name it self is in that format only.

Comment: You don't need to explain, we've all had to suffer the stupidity of the decisions of others. Whomever created something which needed a `CONTPE_` prefix because they were unable to read/locate files named already using the string `CONTPE_` is to blame.